# The accepted answer check mark is almost indistinguishable between active/inactive

Tags: bug, design, accepted-answer, accessibility

The active vs inactive checkmarks are very difficult to tell apart on this site:

> [image: active check]
>   [image: inactive check]

When I'm scrolling down the page it's hard to tell which answer I've actually accepted (or if there is one). Yesterday I genuinely mistook the inactive check for being an active check on an answer, and I have good eyesight without colour blindness.

They both look greyish upon the yellow background.

Their [contrast ratio with regards to each other](http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/#rgb%28129%2C129%2C133%29-on-rgb%2889%2C138%2C30%29) is 1.1:1, or in other words their visual contrast is next to nonexistent.

<sup>(On [a checker that gives us an extra decimal place](http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/), their contrast ratio is 1.07:1. The colours used are #598a1e and #818185.)</sup>

---

Since someone asked  I thought I'd catalog what the above image pair looks like to color blindness based on simulation from [ChromeLens](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromelens/idikgljglpfilbhaboonnpnnincjhjkd):

> [image: protonopia]
>   [image: deuteranopia]

Left: Protonopia, red color blindness. / Right: deuteranopia, green color blindness.
These are the two most common forms of dichromatic color blindness.

> [image: tritanopia]
>   [image: anachromatopsia]

Left: Tritanopia, blue color blindness. / Right: Anachromatopsia, total color blindness.

Comment: It's been on my mind for a long time, but never thought about asking it here. +10 to your question, if I could.

Comment: Mobile app instead of web experience for the win!

Comment: I wonder if colorblindness would exacerbate this.

Comment: @aparente001 I added some colour blindness simulation screenshots. (Pretty sure the answer is yes.)

Comment: Maybe outline would be a viable replacement for a non-accepted check? Filled in for marked and empty outline for not marked.

Comment: @Hank That would work extremely well.

Comment: Has anyone found a similar post on SE meta?

Comment: [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284736/varying-accepted-answer-colors) leads me to believe we may be able to control the design here instead of overall.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146005/can-the-meta-sites-have-non-color-based-visual-cues-to-help-distinguish-them-fro

Comment: @KitZ.Fox That was asked 5 years ago! And yet it remains a request unimplemented. I had upvoted that post months ago.